# How to loop text of an element in JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, loops, arraylist, jlabel

I'm having a problem with loops. How does this loop, loop through different values ​​and display all values ​​on the label, rather than displaying the last value of the array on the label?

[Image of code for loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U86kv.png).

Comment: *"loop through different values ​​and display all values ​​on the label"* DYM display one after the other in time, or all values together at the same time? As an aside, a `JTextArea` or `JList` is better for the second. BTW - Do **not** post images of text or code. Post the text / code itself as an [edit] to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This below code is just copied(written) from your screenshot. which has the minor bug.

```java
sinhvien sv = new sinhvien();
sv.setdata("CC",12);
  sv.setdata("CL",14);
   sv.setdata("CCCL",16);

     s1.add(sv);
```

As you have only created one instance of sv and setting the value 3 times.  Value CCCL override all other two previous values.

```
sv.setdata("CCCL",16);
```

So, at line

```
s1.add(sv);
```

you are actually adding only one instance of sinhvien into the array list.

Debugging: Check the array list size that will give you some clue why you are getting this behaviour. Use the below code after the loop.

```java
//Code to get ArrayList size
System.out.println(sv1.size());
```

Whenever adding items into ArrayList make sure each item has a new instance of the sinhvien.

Please try the below code,

```
sinhvien sv = new sinhvien();
sv.setdata("CC",12);
sv1.add(sv);

sv = new sinhvien();
sv.setdata("CL",14);
sv1.add(sv);

sv = new sinhvien();
sv.setdata("CCCL",16);
sv1.add(sv);
```

Note: Replace above code inside the jButton1ActionPerormed method and before the for a loop. This is nowhere loop issue. It is assignment issue.